# Set "NULL" in Empty cells in CsvReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv

Here is my code:

```
using (System.Net.WebResponse tmpRes = tmpReq.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream tmpStream = tmpRes.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (System.IO.TextReader tmpReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(tmpStream))
        {
            string fileContents = tmpReader.ReadToEnd();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileContents.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fileContents[i] == "")
                {
                    fileContents[i] = "null";
                }
            }
            using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(fileContents))
            {}
       }
    }
}
```

this shows error 'string' to 'char' convert implicitly. Is there any other way to set **"NULL"** in empty fields in CSVReader

Comment: Where do you use the `CSVReader` at all?

Comment: And there's a few CSVReaders out there - which one are you using?

Comment: read CSV from ftpwebrequest

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `CsvReader` at all. You are also not splitting the string by your delimiter to get "cells". However, you can load a `DataTable` from the `CsvReader` and modify that.

Here's an example presuming tab as delimiter:

```
var tblCSV = new DataTable();
using (System.Net.WebResponse tmpRes = tmpReq.GetResponse())
using (System.IO.Stream tmpStream = tmpRes.GetResponseStream())
using (System.IO.TextReader tmpReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(tmpStream))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(tmpReader, true, '\t', '"', '\0', '\0', ValueTrimmingOptions.All))
{
    csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ParseError;
    csv.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent;
    csv.ParseError += csv_ParseError;
    csv.SkipEmptyLines = true;
    // load into DataTable
    tblCSV.Load(csv, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, csvTable_FillError);
}
```

Now loop the rows and columns and modify them accordingly:

```
foreach(DataRow row in tblCSV.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn col in tblCSV.Columns)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Field<string>(col)))
            row.SetField(col, "null");
    }
}
```

**Update** related to your comment:

> I wants to add NULL value in empty cells in sql database when the csv
>   data Save in database. Is there any other way?

You could simply use the loop above to update your table instead:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (DataRow row in tblCSV.Rows)
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table(Col1,Col2) VALUES (@Col1,Col2);", con))
        {
            string col1 = row.Field<string>("Col1");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col1))
                col1 = null;
            string col2 = row.Field<string>("Col2");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col2))
                col2 = null;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", col1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", col2);
            int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wants to add NULL value in empty cells in sql database when the csv data Save in database. Is there any other way, thanks for answering